# JVM crashing with second post method in Django

Tags: python, jvm, jpype

i am trying to build API for my nlp project using Django. I have JAR file and running it with JVM using Jpype in Python. Its working very well with the first POST but its crashing with the second post method without any exception.

I thought its cause of JVM and tried following code but didnt work:

```
if not jp.isJVMStarted():
    print('JVM starting...')
    jp.startJVM(jp.getDefaultJVMPath(), "-Djava.class.path=%s" % JAR_PATH)
    TurkishMorphology = jp.JClass('zemberek.morphology.TurkishMorphology')
    Paths = jp.JClass('java.nio.file.Paths')
else:
    print('JVM shutting down...')
    jp.shutdownJVM()
    print('JVM starting...')
    jp.startJVM(jp.getDefaultJVMPath(), "-Djava.class.path=%s" % JAR_PATH)
```

My all code:

```
def getMorfoloji(sentence):
    JAR_PATH = r'bin\zemberek-full.jar'

    if not jp.isJVMStarted():
        print('JVM starting...')
        jp.startJVM(jp.getDefaultJVMPath(), "-Djava.class.path=%s" % JAR_PATH)
        TurkishMorphology = jp.JClass('zemberek.morphology.TurkishMorphology')
        Paths = jp.JClass('java.nio.file.Paths')
    else:
        print('JVM shutting down...')
        jp.shutdownJVM()
        print('JVM starting...')
        jp.startJVM(jp.getDefaultJVMPath(), "-Djava.class.path=%s" % JAR_PATH)

    TurkishMorphology = jp.JClass('zemberek.morphology.TurkishMorphology')
    Paths = jp.JClass('java.nio.file.Paths')
    morphology = TurkishMorphology.createWithDefaults()
    analysis = morphology.analyzeSentence(sentence)
    results = morphology.disambiguate(sentence, analysis).bestAnalysis()
    analysis_result = ''
    for i in results:
        analysis_result += str(i)
        analysis_result += ' -- '
    print(analysis_result)
    jp.shutdownJVM()
    return analysis_result
```

How can i keep running JVM and not let it stop?

Comment: Do not call `shutdownJVM`. Only one JVM instance can be created per process.

Comment: I tried that way but didnt work. Its still crashing with the second post method.